# Is there a way in Power Query to calculate a running total based upon two columns that resets based on a text value?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create a running total in Power Query for each month of each fiscal year that resets on the start of a new fiscal year.

I can create a running total for the entire column, but I cannot figure out how to reset the total each time ClosedMonth is equal to April / when the fiscal year changes.

I would like to perform this in Power Query because I am loading data from a database and would like the table to automatically update each day when the Power BI refresh is scheduled.

[image: Current Table called Monthly Sums]

The result I am trying to achieve for the running total column would be:

[image: Desired column result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function named fnAddRunningSum

```
(MyTable as table) as table =>
//see:  https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-do-a-running-Sum-by-group-in-Power-Query/td-p/290123
let Source = Table.Buffer(MyTable),
TableType = Value.Type(Table.AddColumn(Source, "Running Sum", each null, type number)),
Cumulative = List.Accumulate(Source[Count],{},(cumulative,amount) => cumulative & {List.Last(cumulative, 0) + amount}),
AddedRunningSum = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source)&{Cumulative},TableType)
in AddedRunningSum
```

then create query

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped" = Table.Group(Source, {"ClosedFiscalYear"}, {{"AllData", fnAddRunningSum}}),
#"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped", "AllData", {"ClosedMonth", "Count", "Index", "Running Sum"}, {"ClosedMonth", "Count", "Index", "Running Sum"})
in #"Expanded AllData"
```